# open graph in a window with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
***import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])***
```

At school it used to open a new window with the graphic (and then we can work on the graph: legend, axis, etc..), and I need to do the same with my computer but the graphe is stuck in the console.

Does someone know how to separate the graphic from the python windows? (I'm french I might not understand what you mean, please use simple words)

Comment: Try adding `plt.figure()
plt.show()` to your code

Comment: What console are you using to run your code? IPython? Qt console? If you're just using a terminal or command prompt the plot shouldn't be embedded in the window. Then, as others suggest, you can get the window using `plt.show()`. You can also turn it on permanently with [`plt.ion()`](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode)

Comment: I use anaconda, I talked to a friend who told me this is why I can't have a new window, so I'm going to use Ipython now. I hope it will work. Thank  you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

plt.show()
```